# VirtualBox: Host can not SSH to Guest

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtualization, suse

i'm having some issue with m VirtualBox installation, 6.1.22.
I have a VM with SUSE (SL12P1) for 64bit as a guest operative system, I have already installed the extension package and I'm trying to reach the guest from the host-system (Windows10) using ssh.
I have set the network adapter as "Bridge", in this way the guest has a 192.168.120.x IP, which i verified with **ifconfig** while the host has an IP of 192.168.120.y.
I can ping the guest from the host, but I cannot ssh the guest from the host system.
Notice that:

1. The firewall has been disabled
2. I have enabled Hyper-V virtualization.
3. I have tried setting the network adapter as NAT, and use port forwarding, but the ssh does not work either

Comment: How does the failing SSH connection look like? Are you getting a "connection refused" message or is it failing after some timeout with a different message? Does SSH work within the guest with "localhost" as the SSH target, so that the guest would SSH to itself?

Comment: i solved this, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firewall for SuSE was active by default, after disabling it everything worked.